# SimpleWeather.js location update not working on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, location

I'm working on a pretty basic weather app using **SimpleWeather.js** and it works fine on pc's **(as far as I can tell)** as well as android devices.

Here it is working: http://www.joshivity.com/asfuck

**My issue:** I can't get iOS devices to both, Automatically update location on pageload or update location manually when clicking "Update location".

**Here is the location code:**

```
$('#locate').on('click', function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    loadWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude); 
  });
});
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: glad you solved your problem!  you could either answer your own question or delete the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Chromes default (on mobiles) is set to "never" use location services. So after having changed that, it seems to be working!